# Unable to parse jboss log file with respect to timestamp

Tags: jboss

I am trying to parse jboss log. But unable to do so as i think the date & time data is not getting parsed successfully. The date-time format is as below:
"2018-11-06 00:00:00,454 SEVERE [datasweep.plantops.server]"
I am trying to parse it with custom format as:
"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601: syslog_timestamp}"
But i am unable to parse the data. Please help..

Comment: I think you might want to provide a little bit more information as what you're trying to accomplish but did you try `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp}.*`

Comment: What version of JBoss AS, JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using?